# css last clicked link menu/no menu

Tags: theming, navigation

I have searched and searched and found many possible solutions but none of them work for me.

I have a very odd website setup (the client wants it that way)
Setup (all next to each other):

Main menu (Menu block)           Submenu (regular block)                 Main content (body)

What I need is the following: When a user clicks on a Main menu item the main menu item gets another color (last cliked menu link).
When the user then clicks on a submenu item that submenu item gets another color (last clicked link). The main menu item can still have the color but this doesn't have to be.
I just want a css rule to change the color of the last clicked link. So not just menu link but just the last link. Is it possible with just CSS or do I need something more? :)

Comment: try using `.my-class-name:active { // do something; }`

Comment: else, you will need to use jQuery with a cookie, in which the cookie stores the name of the `div` that was last clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, i'll look further into it with your information!